# Convex Hull for all linestrings (ca. 1Million) in a Geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a Geopandas dataframe with ca. 1million linestrings for which I want to calculate their convex hull with the corresponding tool (GeoSeries.convex_hull) from Geopandas. It results in a very long calculation time (ca. 4hours). Does someone has an idea how to do this faster?

The Geodataframe looks like this:

```
   s_p_ed_hik  length lanes  i                                         geometry
0    2.658196   4.263  None  0  LINESTRING (8.52441 47.39506, 8.52443 47.39502)
1    2.658196   4.263  None  0  LINESTRING (8.52441 47.39506, 8.52443 47.39502)
2    2.874100   4.343  None  0  LINESTRING (8.52443 47.39502, 8.52449 47.39502)
...
```

Here are the statistics about the length of the Linestrings of my Geopandas Dataframe:

```
count    1063284.000000
mean         12.693328
std          13.335160
min           0.385000
25%           4.956000
50%           9.507000
75%          13.638000
max         287.713000
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `pygeos` installed - https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency. That will give you vectorized operation and big speedup.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygeos
```

You can also try `dask-geopandas` to do it multi-core.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas.git
```

https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas

Comment: Thanks. Pygeos did not make any difference for the execution time.
I compared with: `gpd.options.use_pygeos = True/False`, both take for 56.000 linestrings 62sec.

with *dask_geopands* I get the following error when executing this code:
```import dask_geopandas
ddf = dask_geopandas.from_geopandas(paths_7000, npartitions=8)

paths_7000_HULL=ddf.unary_union
paths_7000_HULL=paths_7000_HULL.convex_hull
print(paths_7000_HULL)```
*AttributeError: 'Scalar' object has no attribute 'convex_hull'*

Comment: Ahhh, you did not say you are doing `unary_union` before `convex_hull`.  Then union itself it the bottleneck and there's not much to do about it apart from making sure you have the latest GEOS 3.9.

Comment: thanks! I came up with a workaround-solution: I converted the Geodataframe back to an OSMnx-MultiDiGraph and then used this code to calculate the convex hull: 1) `node_points = [Point((data['x'], data['y'])) for node, data in testgraph_proj.nodes(data=True)]`,2) `bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull`